# Python: creating new "interpolated" rows based on a specific field in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I'm working with basketball data and I would like to do something akin to resampling but with no Datetime Index and no unique values for the index.

Here is an example of the data I have:

[image: DataFrame of basketball data]

As you probably know, in basketball you can score points up to 3 at a time. However, my analysis requires that every point be logged individually, so instead of "score" or "opp_score" going 0->2 I would like a row at 0, another at 1 and another at 2, with the same data for the other fields as the "2" row.

Here is what I would like it to look like - I left the index blank on the new rows to make it easier to understand what is happening:

[image: Example of processed dataframe with "interpolated" values]

All the techniques I found for interpolation assume that the rows already exist as NaN values or that there is a datetime field to resample on, which is not the case here. I can figure out how to solve this with a clumsy loop using .shift() to check when there is a jump in the score, but I figure there's probably a better way I'm not seeing.

Comment: Can you include your data as text (instead of an image)?

Comment: Sorry, @MichaelSzczesny, I didn't realize it would make the problem harder to work on. I saw that you typed it out, so I appreciate the extra effort you took!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a suitable range and [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).

Create a unique index out of the summed scores. After reindexing with a range backfill column `elapsed` because the values shouldn't be interpolated.

```
df = df.set_index(df.score + df.opp_score)
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1))
df['elapsed'] = df.elapsed.bfill()
df.interpolate().astype(int)
```

Out

```
    period  elapsed  score  opp_score
0        1        0      0          0
1        1       32      1          0
2        1       32      2          0
3        1       72      3          0
4        1       72      4          0
5        1       72      5          0
6        1      127      5          1
7        1      127      5          2
8        1      127      5          3
9        1      148      6          3
10       1      148      7          3
```

Generation of the used dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'period': [1,1,1,1,1],
    'elapsed': [0,32,72,127,148],
    'score': [0,2,5,5,7],
    'opp_score': [0,0,0,3,3]
})
df
```

Out

```
   period  elapsed  score  opp_score
0       1        0      0          0
1       1       32      2          0
2       1       72      5          0
3       1      127      5          3
4       1      148      7          3
```

Comment: Great answer, I had read about reindex but had not made the logic leap that score+opp_score would make a unique, integer-based index that I could use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it without some clumsy loops. If you are familiar with `R`, especially `dplyr`/`tidyr`, you can do it similarly here in python using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which is backended by `pandas`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import (
...     f, lag, tribble, mutate, uncount, replace_na, pmax, 
...     group_by, rev, if_else, select, ends_with
... )
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.period, f.elapsed, f.score, f.opp_score,
...     1,        0,         0,       0,
...     1,        32,        2,       0,
...     1,        72,        5,       0,
...     1,        127,       5,       3,
...     1,        148,       7,       3
... )
>>> (
...     df 
...     >> mutate(   #1
...         score_diff=f.score-lag(f.score), 
...         opp_score_diff=f.opp_score-lag(f.opp_score),
...         count_=pmax(f.score_diff, f.opp_score_diff),
...         count=replace_na(f.count, 1)
...     ) 
...     >> replace_na(0) #2
...     >> group_by(f.elapsed) #2
...     >> uncount(f.count, _id="id") #3
...     >> mutate( #4
...         id=rev(f.id)-1, 
...         score=if_else(f.score_diff>0, f.score-f.id, f.score),
...         opp_score=if_else(f.opp_score_diff>0, f.opp_score-f.id, f.opp_score)
...     )
...     >> select(~f.id, ~ends_with("_diff")) #5
... 
... )
    elapsed  opp_score  period   score
    <int64>    <int64> <int64> <int64>
0         0          0       1       0
1        32          0       1       1
2        32          0       1       2
3        72          0       1       3
4        72          0       1       4
5        72          0       1       5
6       127          1       1       5
7       127          2       1       5
8       127          3       1       5
9       148          3       1       6
10      148          3       1       7

[Groups: elapsed (n=5)]
```

Here are some explanations:

1. The first `mutate` is creating a df like this:

```
   period  elapsed   score  opp_score  score_diff  opp_score_diff     count
  <int64>  <int64> <int64>    <int64>   <float64>       <float64> <float64>
0       1        0       0          0         NaN             NaN       1.0
1       1       32       2          0         2.0             0.0       2.0
2       1       72       5          0         3.0             0.0       3.0
3       1      127       5          3         0.0             3.0       3.0
4       1      148       7          3         2.0             0.0       2.0
```

We created some helper columns to help us expand the rows and some indicators for us to fill up the scores later.

2. `replace_na(0)` and `group_by(f.elapsed)` to replace the `NaN`s with 0 and group the df with column `elapsed` (so that we can operate on each `elapsed` later)
3. `uncount()` just "uncount" the df according to the `count` column (how many times we should duplicate for the current row). The `id` marks the # of the rows that are duplicated. We got a df like this:

```
    elapsed  opp_score  opp_score_diff  period   score  score_diff      id
    <int64>    <int64>       <float64> <int64> <int64>   <float64> <int64>
0         0          0             0.0       1       0         0.0       1
1        32          0             0.0       1       2         2.0       1
2        32          0             0.0       1       2         2.0       2
3        72          0             0.0       1       5         3.0       1
4        72          0             0.0       1       5         3.0       2
5        72          0             0.0       1       5         3.0       3
6       127          3             3.0       1       5         0.0       1
7       127          3             3.0       1       5         0.0       2
8       127          3             3.0       1       5         0.0       3
9       148          3             0.0       1       7         2.0       1
10      148          3             0.0       1       7         2.0       2

[Groups: elapsed (n=5)]
```

4. Now the task is to fill up the right `score` and `opp_score`. The idea is to "un-cumsum" jumps. For example, for `opp_score`, there is a jump from `0` to `3`, we should make it to `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. With the help of the `id` column and indication from the `*_diff` columns, we are able to get it with the second `mutate()`:

```
    elapsed  opp_score  opp_score_diff  period   score  score_diff      id
    <int64>    <int64>       <float64> <int64> <int64>   <float64> <int64>
0         0          0             0.0       1       0         0.0       0
1        32          0             0.0       1       1         2.0       1
2        32          0             0.0       1       2         2.0       0
3        72          0             0.0       1       3         3.0       2
4        72          0             0.0       1       4         3.0       1
5        72          0             0.0       1       5         3.0       0
6       127          1             3.0       1       5         0.0       2
7       127          2             3.0       1       5         0.0       1
8       127          3             3.0       1       5         0.0       0
9       148          3             0.0       1       6         2.0       1
10      148          3             0.0       1       7         2.0       0

[Groups: elapsed (n=5)]
```

5. Finally deselect the helper columns using `select()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not used to how R does things so I appreciate the step by step. The concept of "uncount" and "uncumsum" is new to me and very interesting.